# Nuxt async not work on page reload - firebase

Tags: firebase, async-await, nuxt.js

I have a issue with asyncData() when i refresh the page. If I navigate from list to single item, it work, but if i reload the page i will see an empty object.
In my page i have this :

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{ getItem}}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'
export default {
    data: () => ({
    }),
    computed: {
        ...mapState([
            'single_item'
        ]),
        getItem() {
            return this.single_item
        }
    },

    async asyncData({app,route, params,store}) {
        let type = 'posts'
        let id = params.id
        return store.dispatch('fetchFirebaseSingle', {type,id })
    }
}
</script>
```

in store.js

```
    import { db } from '~/plugins/firebase'
    
    const actions = {
    ....
    
    async fetchFirebaseSingle({commit}, {type, id}) {
        try {
          console.log('fetchFirebaseSingle', type)
          const docRef = await db.collection(type).doc(id)
           docRef.get()
          .then((doc) => {
              if (doc.exists) {
                  const file = doc.data()
                  commit('SET_PAGE_SINGLE', file) 
              } else {
                  // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
                  console.log("No such document!");
              }
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log("Error getting document:", error);
          });
    
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("Error getting document:", e);
        }
      },
    }

const mutations = {
...
    // Set Single Item
    SET_PAGE_SINGLE ( state, single_item) {
      state.single_item = single_item
    },
},
const state = () => ({
      single_item : {},
})
```

I tryed also to call directly from this page the database, but i have same issue. Did someone get similar issue with vuex and firebase or asyncData ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Nothing special here, `asyncData` is not supposed to work on page reload or a refesh (F5) but only with **page transitions**.

> Unlike fetch, the promise returned by the asyncData hook is resolved during route transition

You could use the `fetch()` hook if you don't mind a non-blocking loading.

More info here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/data-fetching#data-fetching